# Adjoint Fokker-Plank operator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, operators, non-equilibrium

In Zwanzig's book "nonequilibrium statistical mechanics" he defines the Fokker-Plank equation for a probability distribution $f$ and with it an operator $D$:

$${ \partial f(a,t) \over \partial t} = \underbrace{- { \partial \over \partial a} (v(a) f)+
{ \partial \over \partial a} B { \partial \over \partial a}  f}_{:=Df}$$

He then claims the adjoint of this operator defined through:

$$\int da \Phi(a) D \Psi(a)=\Psi(a)D^\dagger \Phi(a) $$

is then obviously given by:

$$D^\dagger= v(a) { \partial \over \partial a} +
{ \partial \over \partial a} B { \partial \over \partial a} $$

How on Earth do I get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. $v(a)$ is identified with a left multiplication operator $L_{v(a)}f:= v(a)f$.
2. $L_{v(a)}^{\dagger}=L_{\overline{v(a)}}$; $ \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right)^{\dagger}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial a}$; and $(AB)^{\dagger}=B^{\dagger}A^{\dagger}$.